# SQL Build Task :error MSB4018: Microsoft.Isam.Esent.Interop.EsentVersionStoreOutOfMemoryException

Tags: sql, msbuild

I am not getting any Errors when i Build the Project in My Solution File,but when it was about to Deploy in Testing Environment it says below Error.

What could be the Reasons and How to avoid this in Future.

> **error MSB4018: The "SqlBuildTask" task failed unexpectedly.
>   [msbuild] C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\SSDT\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets(550,5): error MSB4018: Microsoft.Isam.Esent.Interop.EsentVersionStoreOutOfMemoryException: Version store out of memory (cleanup already attempted)
>   **

Comment: try this and update your question,if you face any issues:https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/959162/fix-you-receive-error-msb4018-when-you-run-msbuild-exe-at-a-visual-stu

Comment: Thanks for the Comments Sure!!

Comment: Did the suggested support article work? The link is now dead. 